# Using between query for full date format in Sails.JS Waterline

Tags: datetime, sails.js, waterline

According to [Between Dates using Waterline ORM SailsJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334400/between-dates-using-waterline-orm-sailsjs) it is possible to do a between query on dates in the Waterline adapter like the following:

```
User.find({
    createdAt: { '>': dateFrom, '<': dateTo }
}).exec(/* ... */);
```

However, this does only work with date formats like **2018-04-11**.
Is it somehow possible to use the full ISO8601 date format in this query: e.g. **2018-04-11T12:45:00.000Z**?

**EDIT: Added minimal working example code.**

```
readDataInDateRange: function(req, res) {
    var dateFrom = req.param("dateFrom");
    if (dateFrom == null || dateFrom == ''){
        return res.badRequest();
    }
    var dateTo = req.param("dateTo");
    if (dateTo == null || dateTo == ''){
        return res.badRequest();
    }
    User.find({createdAt: { '>=': dateFrom, '<=': dateTo}})
    .exec(function afterwards(err, users) {
        if (err) {
            sails.log(err);
            return res.serverError(err);
        }
        return res.ok(users);
    });
}
```

Comment: start and end are variables?

Comment: Hi. Yes, they are. Sorry for that, I've added a MWE of code to the question.

Comment: check the response here : https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3543#issuecomment-181495773

Comment: Hi, I will check this soon and put an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use **mongodb** with **CLI**, may practically use

```
    $gt
```

operator that show all value **grater than** specific value. Here we have syntax in **sails.js** that show **[Query Language](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language)** with details.

## grater equal operators

A basic example that we can use to show all data with **criteria** is something like below code.

```
    Model.find({ age: { '<=': 20 }})
```

## greater equal operators

In your case we most filter by dateTime mode.

```
    Model.find({
          where: {
            date: {
              '<=': new Date('2018-08-24T14:56:21.774Z')
            }
          }
        });
```

the time *'2018-08-24T14:56:21.774Z'* is example and you can put all **ISOformat** time here.

## greater and equal operator for time

If your data in database has **timestamp** format you need to change your queries to number instead of date-time format

```
    Model.find({
          where: {
            createdAt: {
              '<=': new Date('2018-08-24T14:56:21.774Z').getTime()
            }
          }
        });
```

**Date** is global object is JavaScript that can instantiated and create new time class. with **.getTime()** timestamp can be generated.

## Query time between two other times

Or in case that the developer wants to collect data between two times, I suggest using below syntax that is correct.

```
    Model.find({
          where: {
            updatedAt: {
              '>': new Date('2018-08-21T14:56:21.774Z').getTime(),
              '<': new Date('2018-08-25T14:56:21.774Z').getTime()
            }
          }
        });
```

Checked them all and don't need worry about correction! ;)